# Core Data Swift 3 Relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have two entities, Device and MDM. Device has two attributes, asset_tag and location. MDM has two attributes, asset_tag and os. I am trying to fetch asset_tag, os, and location for each asset_tag device. I had Xcode create my subclasses:

```
extension Device {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Device> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Device>(entityName: "Device")
    }

    @NSManaged public var asset_tag: String?
    @NSManaged public var location: String?
    @NSManaged public var devices: MDM?

}

extension MDM {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MDM> {
        return NSFetchRequest<MDM>(entityName: "MDM")
    }

    @NSManaged public var asset_tag: String?
    @NSManaged public var os: String?
    @NSManaged public var mdms: Device?

}
```

My fetch request is as follows:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
            request = Device.fetchRequest()
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [Device]
```

Not sure how to get something like `device.mdms.os` to work to get the OS of a specific device.

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, your naming is confusing, please consider the convention. A one-to-one relationship is `device: Device` (singular), a one-to-many relationship is `devices : NSSet` (plural).

Comment: I reversed my relationships and had Xcode remake my subclasses so now it  looks like this:  `@NSManaged public var devices: Device`

Comment: Once again, `devices` (plural) implies **many** devices. The corresponding type is `NSSet`. Otherwise (**one** device, singular) use `device` (without trailing  `s`).

Comment: OK I changed it. If I want to reference a device and it's os. I assume it would be something like `device.mdms.os` but how do I set it up to do that? Something like this: `let devices = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Device", in: context)`

Comment: Like the string properties you have set the relationships in code. Create the devices, create the mdms and set the relationships (pseudocode) `newDevice.mdm = newMDM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the names of your relationships backwards. Right now, `Device` has a relationship called `devices` of type `MDM`, and `MDM` has a relationship called `mdms` of type `Device`. That means you'd get the value of `os` for a `Device` with `device.devices.os`, which is probably not how you want to do it.

To fix it you probably want to reverse the names of those relationships-- in `Device`, change the name from `devices` to `mdms`, and in `MDM`, change the name from `mdms` to `devices`. In general the name of a relationship should describe the thing it relates to, not the thing that has the relationship.

Comment: ok and then once thats done, how do I reference the values with `device.devices.os`. Do I set it up like:

`let devices = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Device", in: context)` and then use `devices.mdms.os`?

Comment: You can create instances, and fetch instances that you've created. That line of code looks up the `Device` entity from your data model but does not create any instances. If you're not sure about how to do that, see Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CreatingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH5-SW1)

Comment: Would it be easier to set up a sqlite store instead, since I am more used to database SQL than core data.

Comment: You can use SQLite directly if you like. Whether it's a good idea depends on what your app needs. The SQL might be easier but you'll have more overhead converting between model objects and rows, maintaining foreign keys yourself instead of letting Core Data think about that, etc.

Comment: Where does it talk about creating instances? I had Xcode create my subclasses for me based on my object model.

Comment: The first section on the page I linked to is titled "Creating Managed Objects" and includes sample code showing how to create new instances.

Comment: I already inserted data with this:

`assert(assetTag.count == location.count, "Both arrays must have the same number of items")
        for i in 0..<assetTag.count {
            
            let device = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Device", into: context) as! Device
            
            
            
            device.asset_tag = assetTag[i]
            device.location = location[i]`

Comment: Ok well, I'm not sure where you're going with this at this point. I answered your original question. If you have more questions, post a new question here.